# How to break to new line in Fortran when printing?

Tags: fortran, gfortran

It is very simple query but I'm not able to find the exact solution. 
How to break to new line when printing in Fortran?

for example

```
print*,'This is first line'
print*,'This is second line'
```

I want following output

```
This is first line

This is Second line
```

That is add space between two lines.

In java we use `\n` and in html using `<br>` does the job..but how to achieve same in Fortran?

Comment: Please try to be more clear in your question - formatting can help (https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 9):

There are several ways to print two lines of output.

```
program foo
   print *, 'This is the first line'
   print *, 'This is the second line'
end program
```

is one way to achieve what you want.  Another is to do

```
program foo
   write(*,'(A,/,A)') 'This is the first line', 'This is the second line'
end program foo
```

And, yet another way

```
program foo
   write(*,'(A)') 'A' // achar(13) // achar(10) // 'B'
end program foo
```

And with some compilers you can use options

```
program foo
   write(*,'(A)') 'A\r\nB'
end program foo
```

Compiling with the following options yields:

```
$ gfortran -o z -fbackslash a.f90 && ./z
  A
  B
```

Comment: NO ....I want the space or line between two print statement...? is there any way to achieve this...in html i can use <br> but in fortran I didn't see any option instead if I write print statement separately at some distance below.

Comment: Of course, just add `print *` between the print statements.  BTW, your question wasn't stated too clearly. :(

Answer (score 8):

There are a number of ways to manage what you want.  We can either print *blank records* or explicitly add a newline character.

A newline character is returned by the intrinsic function `NEW_LINE`:

```
print '(2A)', 'First line', NEW_LINE('a')
print '(A)', 'Second line'
```

`NEW_LINE('a')` is likely to have an effect like `ACHAR(10)` or `CHAR(10,KIND('a'))`.

A blank record can be printed by having no output item:

```
print '(A)', 'First line'
print '(A)'
print '(A)', 'Second line'
```

Or we can use *slash editing*:

```
print '(A,/)', 'First line'
print '(A)', 'Second line'
```

If we aren't using multiple print statements we can even combine the writing using these same ideas.  Such as:

```
print '(A,:/)', 'First line', 'Second line'
print '(*(A))', 'First line', NEW_LINE('a'), NEW_LINE('a'), 'Second line'
```

`NEW_LINE('a')` could also be used in the format string but this doesn't seem to add much value beyond slash editing.

Comment: Ah, good catch with `NEW_LINE`.  I had forgotten about that intrinsic subprogram.